# python script calling tempfile not working in windows, works in Ubuntu

Tags: python, windows, temporary-files

I'm having to use a script temporarily in windows, rather than my usual Ubuntu. I have found that the script fails to run due to calling "tempfile" not working in windows. I've attached the snippet below. where I get the error

File "phys_features_windows.py", line 70, in extract_LCR
with open(tmp_LCR.name, 'w') as f_LCR:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\Henry\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpz6wx32mx'

I've also tried the tweak suggested of calling "delete=False" but this just changed the error to

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

in the "out" line

I assume that the file creation works differently in windows, or the way the file is called does, and so the script can't find the temporary file - but unfortunately I can't find the solution after further testing and reading. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks

original code:

```
def extract_LCR(seq):
    tmp_LCR = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, delete_on_close=False) #flag for windows
    with open(tmp_LCR.name, 'w') as f_LCR:
         f_LCR.write('>1\n' + str(seq))
    tmp_LCR.seek(0)

    out = subprocess.Popen(['segmasker', '-in', str(tmp_LCR.name)],
           stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

with line 2 changed to

```
tmp_LCR = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, delete_on_close=False) #flag for windows
```

producing the second error.

I am happy to provide more of the code if needed but the script is long, and I'd prefer not to attach the whole thing!

Many thanks!

Comment: I realise I accidentally deleted the errors - i'm adding them back in now! apologies

Comment: Why are you manually reopening the file? `tmp_LCR` is *already* an open file handle, using `open` to open it again (getting *another* file handle) is pointless. Just do `with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w') as f_LCR:`, then (within the `with` block) `f_LCR.write('>1\n' + str(seq))`, `f_LCR.flush()`, `out = subprocess.Popen(['segmasker', '-in', f_LCR.name], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)`. The important part added there is explicitly `flush` the buffer to disk, so your `subprocess` will see the full contents (nothing stuff in user mode buffers).

Comment: Only note of consequence: Make sure to `wait` or `communicate` to the `subprocess.Popen` object before leaving the `with` (or at least ensure enough work is done that the subprocess has time to open the file and read the contents), so the file isn't deleted before the `subprocess` can see it. Unless you *must* let the subprocess run in the background, the safest approach is to use `subprocess.run` instead of `subprocess.Popen`, so the subprocess is guaranteed to run to completion before you leave the `with` and the file is cleaned up.

Comment: @ShadowRanger - OP needs `delete_on_close=False` and needs to close the file so that the subprocess doesn't have the same problem.

Comment: @tdelaney: Sure. Not sure why you reopened this though, it's 100% a duplicate. It's fine to add answers to the duplicate if you think it's incompletely answered, why spread the answers out like this?

Comment: @ShadowRanger - because OP also needed to change the flags used on the call and still needed to specifically close the file. The accepted answer was only a part of the solution and in my opinion wasn't close enough to be a dup.

Answer (score 0):

Windows won't let you open a file for writing that is already open. `NamedTemporaryFile` gives you a writable file object. Use it in a `with` clause and close the file before making the subprocess call to make sure the file has been flushed and is usable by the called program. This takes you back to the default `delete=True` so that your temporary file is cleaned up when the `with` terminates.

```
def extract_LCR(seq):
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile("w", delete_on_close=False) as tmp_LCR: #flag for windows
        tmp_LCR.write('>1\n' + str(seq))
        tmp_LCR.close()
        out = subprocess.Popen(['segmasker', '-in', str(tmp_LCR.name)],
           stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        out.communicate()
```

Comment: Hi, 

Thanks for your answer, Unfortunately I'm getting the error "TypeError: NamedTemporaryFile() got an unexpected keyword argument 'delete_on_close' " 

Is this a version issue? I can't find any reason why delete_on_close wouldn't be accepted? 

for reference I'm using Python 3.8.10 (in windows as before) 

Thanks again!

Comment: @HKT - turns out you are right. That's 3.12+. I looked at the code for 3.8. If `delete=True` it opens the file O_TEMPORARY which will delete on close. I don't have a Windows up to test, but perhaps you could do `delete=False` and then do `tmp_LCR.file.close()` which will reach around tempflle's file object and close the file. Do that the before the subprocess call.